# XCode stops multiple times at breakpoints

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging, lldb

XCode 4.5.2 with lldb debugger

When debugging in various places, XCode likes to stop multiple times at certain breakpoints.  Some only 2 or 3 times, others 10+ times.

Also, when stepping through the code, the current line marker often jumps up 2 or 3 lines and appears to execute the same code multiple times.  It's not actually executing multiple times as I've tested this with NSLog statements.

Comment: Do you have the optimizer flags on?  This kind of weird program flow is expected if so.

Comment: Pretty normal.  The machine code jumps around quite a bit and the debugger simply tries to associate a machine instruction with the closest line.  Especially with loops and at procedure end you may see things jump back and forth several times.

Comment: It was the optimizer flags!  @amattn, if you post this as an answer I'll except it for others who may have this problem.  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you are in Debug scheme or double check that the optimizer flags are off in Build Settings.

Comment: In the past I had changed my LLVM Debug mode optimization flags to faster & smaller (just like release mode) because I was having a crash that only occurred in release mode.  I just changed them back to "No Optimization" and debugging works properly again.  Thanks @amattn!